# Laravel Delete Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

In Laravel 4 `Illuminate\Database\Query` in a `Builder` class `delete` function accepts `null` as an `id` parameter. And behaivor of this function implies that if I have something like:

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->delete();
```

And if `$id` will be passed as a `null`, it will truncate the whole table. Which means that besides standard validation, I have to  wrap every delete statement with `! is_null($id)` validation. Is it a security breach or it's considered as a standard practice?

Comment: the same statement also work with laravel version 5.4

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what that parameters purpose is. It's simply a *shortcut* for the example you have shown. If you have a users ID you can delete them without writing that `where` clause.

```
DB::table('users')->delete($id);
```

The above is identical to this:

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->delete();
```

You'd obviously perform a check prior to using any of these methods to ensure that a valid ID has been supplied. I wouldn't say it's a security breach, just something you as a developer needs to be aware of when developing your application. You don't just go willy nilly deleting things without first validating the input.

Comment: @Jason, thank you for the great solution but if primary key has different name than id, how to use DB::table('users')->delete($id); in this case?

Comment: @SachinVairagi add this line in your model: protected $primaryKey = 'my_column';

Comment: in my_column, add your column name that is your primary key

Answer (score 0):

```
 DB::table('table_name')->where('table_id', $request['request_id'])->delete();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.