# put single row to variable and delete it at same time with one query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, lumen

I have a `password_resets` table in mysql database and i want to get single raw of data and delete it with one query in Lumen with `DB` facade like this:

`$reset_row = DB::table('password_resets')->where('token', $request->token)->first()->delete();`

But i have a error :

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::delete()
```

i try this code :

```
  $reset_row = DB::table('password_resets')->where('token', $request->token)
  //do my work whith $reset_row->first();
  $reset_row->delete();
```

But i think this way use 2 query to do this work.

**NOTE** : i know i can not delete and reason is `first()` method )return it to array)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please post the exact error you receive. (edit it into the question, do not post it as a comment)

Comment: question updated.sorry for my mistake.(i have error in in first code)

Comment: As far as i know you should use models as often as possible instead of using the DB facade

Comment: yes.i think i should migrate to model for reset password!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I Think to  create model for reset password and Use it like this:

**1.** set primary key to token by set it on model like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030716/change-default-primary-key-in-eloquent)

**2.** use find method to find token ([document for find method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models))

use this way:

```
$reset=PasswordReset::find($token);
//work with $reset
$reset->delete()
```

**NOTE:** : for set primary key to string col see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582535/laravel-5-2-use-a-string-as-a-custom-primary-key-for-eloquent-table-becomes-0/34715309) too

Answer (score 0):

> Actually no need to use ->first(). Bcz your token is unique.
>
> if you need try this.

```
$reset_row = DB::table('password_resets')->where('token', $request->token)
    ->Limit(1)->delete();
```

> I think it is possible to use "limit" with "delete".

Comment: i used this way and i get ```Trying to get property 'email' of non-object``` Error.this way don't save raw in reset_row variable !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply chain the delete method to your Query Buider.
No need to select the first on since you want to delete them, not select them.

`DB::table('password_resets')->where('token', $request->token)->delete();`

Its already answered in another post in StackOverflow.

You can use this answer too
[laravel-delete-query-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722959/laravel-delete-query-builder) and you can also look at the official documentation about [deleting using the query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#deletes)

Comment: i know i can get it by this way(!) but i want to store it in reset_row variable first!!!!!

Comment: Calm down, adding extra exclamation marks isn't going to help.